# How to connect to rabbitMQ for Azure using Serverless framework

Tags: azure, rabbitmq, azure-functions, serverless, serverless-framework

Is rabbitMQ for azure functions not supported in serverless framework?

There is a documentation corresponding to aws: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/rabbitmq
but I didn't find anything for Azure.

When I tried something like:

```
service: my-app

provider:
  name: azure
  location: West US
  runtime: nodejs14

plugins:
  - serverless-azure-functions
  - serverless-webpack

functions:
  currentTime:
    handler: main.endpoint
    events:
      - rabbitMQ: SMS
        name: myQueueItem 
        connectionStringSetting: rabbitMQConnection
```

then was getting the error: "Binding  rabbitMQTrigger not supported".

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `rabbitmq` event is only available for `aws` provider and you cannot use it with Azure.